# How to get the 'href' value from a specific name in the HTML code

Tags: python, python-requests, href

I want to create a code which gets the href=... of a specific name in the HTML code. A part of the HTML code looks like this:

```
class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirts/hcir4dp5z/ntsf95gld">Tupac Hologram Tee</a> == $0
```

There are more parts in the HTML code that look like this. Because there are multiple products on the website (Supreme). I have got the name of the product -> Tupac Hologram Tee . Does someone know how I can get the href value from this specific line instead of a other line in the html code which also includes a href= ?

This was my code which printed out all the href links on the page. But I just want that specific link from the product with Tupac Hologram Tee as the name.

```
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
word = r.html.links
print(word)
```

Comment: So you want to web scrape? Look up ``BeautifulSoup``

Comment: Can you post a thinned out sample of the html so we can see the details of the elements and text?

Comment: <a class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirts/hcir4dp5z/ntsf95gld">Tupac Hologram Tee</a> == $0

Comment: talking out the code to do so:  For line in myfile,if line contains (product), split on spaces, for each split segment, if it contains "href", split on (double quotes) grab split[1] (part two of the split.)

Comment: is this the code? :)

Comment: Can't you access the contents/text of the tag?

Answer (score 0):

If your code prints a list of all lines including href, couldn't you just search for the line you want from them? It would be a bit easier to help if the output and more code was visible.

Comment: yeah, but there are a lot of lines and I don't know how to find the one i want

Comment: I meant, write more code that filters out those results, not manually searching it.